# Unable to paste view key when creating a View Only Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I’m using ./monero-wallet-cli to create a view only wallet on Windows 10.
First the command I’m using ask for the address. I paste it in and hit enter. Then I’m asked for the secret view key. I’m now not able to paste anymore, and can’t either use keyboard to do inputs manually. My clipboard is holding the secret view key - I checked this in notepad. Antivirus has the correct setup for excluding monero miner stuff. Daemon is running as well and the complete blockchain is locally running on same host. It’s the newest version I’m using 0.17.1.0 and Windows 10 is fully updated as well.

Comment: What command or shortcut are you using to paste?

Comment: Hi. I’m using CTRL + V for paste but has also tried using the interface GUI in CLI client, but when having view key in clipboard nothing will paste. Just blank. But if pasting elsewhere (Notepad) the view key is there. Very odd.

Comment: Did you try right click on the command prompt (top bar) -> paste (for `monero-wallet-cli`)?